# Is it possible to redirect a read to a file in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have one device that generates data and an application that reads the content of that device. I think the setup can be examplified like this:

device      --> `echo "ABC" >> /dev/mydevice`

application --> `cat /dev/mydevice`

application output: "ABC"

Is there a way I can force the application to get a different source of data when it reads from `/dev/mydevice`, considering that I can't modify (write/move) `/dev/mydevice` nor change the path that is read by the application.

I would need something like this:

device      --> `echo "ABC" >> /dev/mydevice`

me          --> `echo "123" >> myinput.txt`

me          --> force redirect `/dev/mydevice` to `myinput.txt`

application --> `cat /dev/mydevice`

application output: "123"

Comment: Perhaps a chroot helps.

Comment: Might be even easier with proot.

Comment: They don't exactly "force redirect a read to a file" though. Rather they just allow you to fake a /dev/(mydevice) without breaking the current system.

Comment: Though the fake can be a named pipe, I guess

Comment: Btw, what makes you think you can't just `rm /dev/mydevice`?

Comment: Or is it really a device that you can both read and write and you want the program to write to one path but read from another when it doesn't?

Comment: @TomYan For example, in a different scenario, if the kernel gets some attribute from a hardware and puts it in /sys/../X, I can't remove or edit /sys. In this scenario, can I somehow redirect the reads from /sys/../X to /home/myX ?

Comment: Ugh now it becomes /sys/ and an attribute...which is quite a different story. I don't think I can help further.

Comment: @TomYan I am just giving one example in which I can't remove/modify/move my file. What I want is to know if it is possible to redirect the read of a file, without removing, modifing or moving the file and without modifying the application.

Comment: Well, all I can say is, if you really mean like Object A can't be changed *at all* (from Object B's point of view), *but* you want Object A's reaction(s) to B to change, that's like illogical in general to me. (Can't be changed at all but change?)

Comment: And I have given you idea(s) to fake an Object A to Object B while keeping the real Object A behind the scene serving others. That's the best I could think of (or the closest thing I find logical).

Comment: Maybe you can patch proot (or create something similar yourself) to create a fake file by binding different actions to different files behind the scene...

Comment: Or change the kernel so that it reacts specifically differently to a certain action of a certain file...

Comment: I was reading about chroot, and it might work. If I use chroot /home/user/, and add a /home/user/dev/mydevice, when the application calls `cat /dev/mydevice` it will cat the /home/user/dev/mydevice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100256/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-klaus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [proot](https://github.com/proot-me/proot) (you probably want to build its git master btw).

While it doesn't exactly "redirect (just) reading of a file to another file without changing the file in any way", it allows you to create an environment where all access to a file (or actually a path) is done to another file behind the scene:

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ file /dev/zero /dev/urandom
/dev/zero:    character special (1/5)
/dev/urandom: character special (1/9)
[tom@archlinux ~]$ proot -b /:/ -b /dev/urandom:/dev/zero
[tom@archlinux ~]$ file /dev/zero /dev/urandom
/dev/zero:    character special (1/9)
/dev/urandom: character special (1/9)
[tom@archlinux ~]$ hexdump -C -n 16 /dev/zero
00000000  18 d1 ee 6f a8 9e 1e ac  99 60 db 79 79 e0 d9 f5  |...o.....`.yy...|
00000010
[tom@archlinux ~]$ hexdump -C -n 16 /dev/zero
00000000  03 60 15 53 f7 e3 15 43  05 7e ef 8e 68 8b 6b 49  |.`.S...C.~..h.kI|
00000010
[tom@archlinux ~]$ logout
[tom@archlinux ~]$ hexdump -C -n 16 /dev/zero
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010
[tom@archlinux ~]$
```

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 > sdc
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
16 bytes copied, 9.8566e-05 s, 162 kB/s
[tom@archlinux ~]$ file /home/tom/sdc 
/home/tom/sdc: data
[tom@archlinux ~]$ hexdump -C /home/tom/sdc 
00000000  6f 05 42 ee 9f 5d 3a 5d  b4 27 d2 02 40 e4 ff d0  |o.B..]:].'..@...|
00000010
[tom@archlinux ~]$ proot -b /:/ -b /home/tom/sdc:/dev/sdc
[tom@archlinux ~]$ file /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: data
[tom@archlinux ~]$ hexdump -C /dev/sdc
00000000  6f 05 42 ee 9f 5d 3a 5d  b4 27 d2 02 40 e4 ff d0  |o.B..]:].'..@...|
00000010
[tom@archlinux ~]$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 >> /dev/sdc
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
16 bytes copied, 0.000101888 s, 157 kB/s
[tom@archlinux ~]$ logout
[tom@archlinux ~]$ hexdump -C /home/tom/sdc 
00000000  6f 05 42 ee 9f 5d 3a 5d  b4 27 d2 02 40 e4 ff d0  |o.B..]:].'..@...|
00000010  5a c8 af 48 59 1c de 00  ba ff 88 a2 82 b4 bb 5c  |Z..HY..........\|
00000020
[tom@archlinux ~]$ file /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: cannot open `/dev/sdc' (No such file or directory)
[tom@archlinux ~]$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind mount something else over `/dev/mydevice`. If you unshare the mount namespace first then the rest of the system will not be affected. Thanks to the [`-r` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370484/108618) you don't need to be root in the first place.

```
unshare -r -m     # run a shell in a new mount namespace
 # Now you _appear_ to be root _locally_ (e.g. your files will appear root's),
 # but to the outside of the shell you're the original user.
mount --bind myinput.txt /dev/mydevice
your_application -with --options and operands
exit              # exit the shell, and hence the mount namespace
```

Non-interactive version:

```
unshare -r -m sh << EOF
mount --bind myinput.txt /dev/mydevice
exec your_application -with --options and operands
EOF
```

Notes:

- `exec` because there's no point in keeping `sh`;
- If you need to run `your_application` as another user, i.e. with `sudo`, then run `unshare` with `sudo`.

---

If you get `unshare failed: Operation not permitted` (especially in Debian) then see [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=808915#10):

> It turns out that the Debian kernel is set up to disable unprivileged users from unsharing the user namespace by default. This can be worked around using:
>
> ```
> sudo su -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone'
> ```

<sup>(There is a typo in the original command. The above citation has been fixed.)</sup>

An alternative is to use `sudo` like this:

```
sudo unshare -m sh << 'EOF'
mount --bind myinput.txt /dev/mydevice
exec sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" your_application -with --options and operands
EOF
```

Either way you most likely need `sudo` to deal with `unshare failed: Operation not permitted`.

---

Proof of concept that doesn't rely on `myinput.txt`, `/dev/mydevice` or `your_application`, so the chances are it will work out of the box:

```
unshare -r -m sh << EOF
mount --bind /etc/fstab /dev/null
exec cat /dev/null
EOF
```

Comment: I tested this option, and it has some advantages, as I am not constrained to the `proot` environment. But I ended up using @TomYan`s solution, as it came first and also solves the problem.